# Jquery check checkbox value then set checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="paid" id="paid-change">
```

which will have value = "1" or "0".I want to check if checkbox value = "1" the checkbox will add checked status on it.
Tks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This code is using pure javascript

```
var chkBox = document.getElementById("paid-change");
if (chkBox.value == 0)
    chkBox.checked = false;
else if (chkBox.value == 1)
    chkBox.checked = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="paid" id="paid-change" value="0">
```

Jquery

```
if($("#paid-change").val() == '1') { // if checkbox value is 1 - marked it checked
   $('#paid-change').prop('checked', true);
} else if($("#paid-change").val() == '0') {  // if checkbox value is 0 - marked it unchecked
   $('#paid-change').prop('checked', false);
}
```

Comment: Tks all of u for helping me.Solved :)